# Prevent VS debugger from time out

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have to debug an asp.net page that takes several minutes to execute. The problem is that
the Visual Studio internal dev server <s>debugger</s> (I am currently using VS2012) times 
out before the page execution finishes.

Is there any way to fix this problem? Please note that I do not want to get VStudio to attach 
to IIS. I just want to know if there is a way to configure the **internal** Web Development Server.

Thanx in advance!

(Thanks SLaks for the edit)

Comment: The server is timing out, not the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

My cheap, dirty answer would be to send data back to the page during the operation. This could serve to keep the connection alive as you appear to be timing out at the browser level.

To properly handle the issue I would break up the operation into multiple steps:

1. MyService.BeginOperation()
2. MyService.UpdateOperation()
3. MyService.EndOperation()

Where the client will call those methods asynchronously to determine application state.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea: I ajaxified the request. This solved my problem!

Comment: Hi @GiorgosBetsos now you have > 10 points you can upvote. Also, there is a holo TickBox underneather the +1/-1 answer score and when you mark an answer as correct it will give you a couple of points. Good luck!